# Multiple stored procedure are not getting called?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Below image contain my code.

[image]

here, only one procedure is invoked at a time.Both procedure are not working .
here if state procedure is commented then city procedure called.
and if city in commented then State procedure is working.

Comment: Provide your code with this image

Comment: Please input your source not as image..

Answer (score 0):

for example , you can call multiple stored procedure like this below code

```
$db = mysqli_connect([...]);  


$r = mysqli_query($db, " CALL getSomething(2); ");  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {  
      print_r($row);  
}  

mysqli_free_result($r);  
mysqli_next_result($db);  

$r = mysqli_query($db, " CALL getSomethingElse(); ");  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {  
      print_r($row);  
}  

mysqli_free_result($r);
mysqli_next_result($db);  
mysqli_close($db);
```

it is important to use the functions mysqli_free_result() and mysqli_next_result() after the MySQL stored procedure is called, otherwise, the code will not work and you may see an error like "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Comment: if you want to know more on this use this url for reference

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904

Comment: do you tried mysqli_free_result($r);  
mysqli_next_result($db);